What System Configuration and postgres Configuration Is Needed to Handle 5000 pgRouting Requests at the same time?
`I’m working on a project where we need to process 5000 concurrent pgRouting requests involving PostgreSQL with the pgRouting extension. The requests will mainly involve route planning and shortest path calculations over a large graph. We need to ensure the system can handle high traffic and provide low-latency responses. System Overview:
Database: PostgreSQL 12 with pgRouting and postgis
Graph Size: around 2 millions
Request Type: Each request will perform routing queries (shortest path, multi-stop, etc.) on the graph.
Concurrency: Expected to handle 5000 concurrent pgRouting requests.
We’re currently considering the following system configuration:
CPU: 8 core
RAM: 64 GB
Key Questions:
PostgreSQL Configuration: What are the best PostgreSQL settings to optimize for high concurrency and pgRouting queries? Specifically, we are looking for recommendations on:
these are my current settings :
max_connections = 5000

shared_buffers = 16GB

effective_cache_size = 48GB

maintenance_work_mem = 2047MB

checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9

wal_buffers = 16MB

default_statistics_target = 100

random_page_cost = 4

work_mem = 419kB

huge_pages = try

min_wal_size = 1GB

max_wal_size = 4GB

max_worker_processes = 8

max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 4

max_parallel_workers = 8

max_parallel_maintenance_workers = 4

Connection Pooling: Should we use connection pooling (e.g., PgBouncer) to manage database connections? If so, what is the recommended pool size and pool mode?
Query Optimization: Are there specific pgRouting query optimizations (e.g., caching query results, query structure, or parameterization) that we should implement to improve the response time for routing queries?
Any recommendations on:
Hardware Setup: CPU, RAM, storage options for optimal PostgreSQL and pgRouting performance.
Database Settings: PostgreSQL configuration tips to handle 5000 concurrent requests with low latency and high throughput.
pgRouting Tuning: pgRouting-specific optimizations for large-scale routing.

Don't focus on parameters. Write the query in question and see how it performs on a realistic data set. Tune the query if necessary. Size the machine so that it can handle the required number of concurrent requests.
